# Is there a way to see a list of a class' methods with their length (no of lines) in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

When refactoring a class that is too large, to get an overview of "problematic" methods I find it useful to see a list of all methods, with the number of lines of each method.

Eclipse of course has a list of the methods of a class (breadcrumbs, Outline view), but I can't see a way to show the number of lines for each method.

Is there a way to see this, in Eclipse, or using some other tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What can be useful to you is Metrics in Eclipse.

Try http://www.stateofflow.com/projects/16/eclipsemetrics and http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net/descriptions/LinesOfCode.html

> Lines of Code in Method
>
> This measure indicates the number of
>   lines a method occupies - a line is
>   determined by the presence of a
>   newline character. It is a very basic
>   measure of size and is susceptible to
>   variation purely on the basis of
>   different formatting styles. However,
>   many users of the Eclipse Metrics
>   plugin asked for it's inclusion, so
>   here it is (...)

Comment: Metrics2 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/metrics2/) is another Eclipse plugin that can do what you want, and more.

Answer (score 3):

[CodePro AnalytiX](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/javadevtools/download-codepro.html) does this (and much more).

---

Edit: or if you just want to know which methods are too big, you can use [checkstyle](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/). It will check that for you, and put warnings where appropriate.